Why the value of the global variable does not change when modified within function
I am programming a Raspberry Pi Pico in C. I have this MWE:
#include "pico/stdlib.h"
#include "pico/cyw43_arch.h"
#include "hardware/uart.h"

#define UART_ID uart0
#define BAUD_RATE 2000000
#define UART_TX_PIN 0
#define UART_RX_PIN 1

uint8_t blink_LED;

void handle_uart_commands() {
    // Function to be called when data is received in the UART.
    while (uart_is_readable(UART_ID)) {
        uint8_t ch = uart_getc(UART_ID);

        switch (ch) {
            case 'b':
                printf("%d", blink_LED); // This sends "0", ok!
                blink_LED = 7;
                printf("%d", blink_LED); // This sends "7", ok!
            break;
        }
    }
}

void init_uart(void) {
    uart_init(UART_ID, BAUD_RATE);
    gpio_set_function(UART_TX_PIN, UART_FUNCSEL_NUM(UART_ID, UART_TX_PIN));
    gpio_set_function(UART_RX_PIN, UART_FUNCSEL_NUM(UART_ID, UART_RX_PIN));

    // Set up a RX interrupt:
    int UART_IRQ = UART_ID == uart0 ? UART0_IRQ : UART1_IRQ; // Select correct interrupt for the UART we are using.
    irq_set_exclusive_handler(UART_IRQ, handle_uart_commands);
    irq_set_enabled(UART_IRQ, true);
    uart_set_irq_enables(UART_ID, true, false);
}

void init_stuff(void) {
    stdio_init_all();
    init_uart();
    hard_assert(cyw43_arch_init() == PICO_OK);
    blink_LED = 3;
}

int main() {
    init_stuff();

    while (true) {
        if (blink_LED) {
            cyw43_arch_gpio_put(CYW43_WL_GPIO_LED_PIN, 1);
            sleep_ms(333);
            cyw43_arch_gpio_put(CYW43_WL_GPIO_LED_PIN, 0);
            sleep_ms(333);
            blink_LED -= 1;
            printf("b"); // Indicate that the LED blinked once.
        }
    }
}

What it is supposed to do:

Blink the LED 3 times upon power on.
Upon receiving b through the UART serial communication, it should blink the LED 7 times.

What it does:

Blinks the LED 3 times upon power on. Ok!
Upon receiving b, the LED does not blink a single time. Not ok.

I added the two printf lines just to see the value of blink_LED, and it sends the right values, meaning it is receiving and correctly processing b. However, the LED does not blink. Moreover, the printf("b") line is only executed 3 times after power on, meaning it never goes back into the if (blink_LED). I don't understand why. Is the value of blink_LED=7 somehow only valid within handle_uart_commands and after that it returns to the previous value?

First thought is what's the value of ch?

Compiler may optimize if (blink_LED) ... blink_LED -= 1; into equivalent of for (int i=0; i<3; i++) .... Declare blink_LED as volatile.

However, even with volatile but without synchronization you'll have race condition.

@dimich adding volatile to the definition of blink_LED fixed this, thanks! Can you upgrade your comment to answer so I accept it?

In case these functions are called by an interrupt service routine, then not only does the variable have to be volatile, you may also need to protect it from race condition bugs. So just adding volatile is not necessarily the whole story.

Not an expert here, but I don't think race condition will matter here, as blink_LED is only modified by one function, and also the time scale is very slow.

If it is only written to from the ISR and only read by from the background program, then you can get away with not having atomic access, as race condition bugs might then only manifest themselves as random update delays (which may be negligible if the blink time is slow) and probably not as data corruption... maybe. Such things are hard to predict without checking the actual disassembly.

>Can you upgrade your comment to answer so I accept it? I don't think my comment deserves to be an answer. Similar to your question is answered for example here. >I don't think race condition will matter here Yes, while you only set non-zero value in the handler. In worst case it may miss blink_LED change during read/modify/write. But if you decide to "stop" blinking by setting blink_LED=0 from interrupt context, it may cause 256 blinks.

I solved this by declaring blink_LED as volatile, i.e.
volatile uint8_t blink_LED;

For my application, this is enough and perfectly works. In the most general case, there could still be a race condition, see comments in the question. However, this is actually the reason why the led was not blinking, so this is actually the answer to the question.
